# What is @license and @publicApi inside comments in Angular or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, comments

I built my Angular app then looked at the built code where I found @license or @publicApi inside comments like you can see in image attached below. I don't know what this thing is and How to create them. Please if anyone know then kindly comment your answer below, It'll be helpful for me to know something new.

[image]

Comment: tags for generating documentation, they have nothing to do with angular

Comment: but when i'm adding tags, it's not getting colourful. It'll be green like other texts inside comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jsDoc annotations used by Google. A good guide in writing those: https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/

For example the @license can be explained: https://jsdoc.app/tags-license.html

```
 The @license tag identifies the software license that applies to any portion of your code.

 You can use any text to identify the license you are using.
```

The public api one seems like it's something Google specific. All these are annotations. They don't change the way the code works.

JSDoc's purpose is to document the API of your JavaScript application or library. It is assumed that you will want to document things like modules, namespaces, classes, methods, method parameters, and so on.

Comment: So how can we can create these annotations?

Comment: Check https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments or you can add them manually with a /** comment.

Comment: As you can see in screenshot, the @something is colourful, but whenever i'm adding it manually it is getting green like normal comments.

Comment: Jsdoc needs to be in a specific format. Copy and paste an entire section from angular to your code and see what happens. Or better yet go to a function of yours and type above it /** and press enter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally i got it. I was just using /* that's why it was not working. Now it's working if i'm using /**

Comment: One more question that, when it should be used? can i use it as beautiful comment  or it has different standards to use.

Comment: Ideally, over every class and public method/member definition. I add them over private methods too for future reference.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your answer.